# Certain NotificationBuilder methods are deprecated in Xamarin.Android, which ones should I use?

Tags: c#, android, push-notification, notifications, xamarin.android

I have been working with Notification.Builder class but some of the options are deprecated apparently, for example `SetSound`, `SetDefaults`, `SetVibrate`, `SetPriority`, etc.

What methods should I use to set these options now? The official Android documentation tells me to use `enableSound` or `enableVibrate` but these are not available in Xamarin.Android.

Does anyone have some advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Notification builder methods have been deprecated but they have been deprecated on API level 26 OR Android Oreo(8.0) and using these methods below them should not be a problem, (FOR NOW!)
Other than that as per the Xamarin release notes the new methods will probably be available in the next release :

For more information please check here :
https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_8/xamarin.android_8.0/